# isset() function is returning true even when item is not set

Tags: php, mysql, isset

Here is my code. For some reason, if I submit the form without placing and passwords in, it still creates the database entry. There are some comments scattered throughout the code, but the code is fairly straightforward. Any ideas?

```
<?php
//signup.php
include 'connect.php';
include 'header.php';

echo '<h3>Sign up</h3>';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
{
    /*The form hasn't been posted yet, display it
      note that the action="" will cause the form to post to the same page it is on */
    echo '<form method="post" action="">
        Username: <input type="text" name="user_name" /><br />
        Password: <input type="password" name="user_pass" /><br />
        Password again: <input type="password" name="user_pass_check" /><br />
        E-mail: <input type="email" name="user_email" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Add category" />
        </form>';
}
else
{
    /* so, the form has been posted, we'll process the data in three steps:
        1.  Check the data
        2.  Let the user refill the wrong fields (if necessary)
        3.  Save the data
    */
    $errors = array(); /* declare the array for later use */

    if(isset($_POST['user_name']))
    {
        //the user name exists
        if(!ctype_alnum($_POST['user_name']))
        {
            $errors[] = 'The username can only contain letters and digits.';
        }
        if(strlen($_POST['user_name']) > 30)
        {
            $errors[] = 'The username cannot be longer than 30 characters.';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $errors[] = 'The username field must not be empty.';
    }

    if(isset($_POST['user_pass']))
    {
        if($_POST['user_pass'] != $_POST['user_pass_check'])
        {
            $errors[] = 'The two passwords did not match.';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $errors[] = 'The password field cannot be empty.';
    }

    if(!empty($errors))
    {
        echo 'Uh-oh.. a couple of fields are not filled in correctly..';
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($errors as $key => $value)
        {
            echo '<li>'.$value.'</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    else
    {
        //the form has been posted without errors, so save it
        //notice the use of mysql_real_escape_string, keep everything safe.
        //also notice the sha1 function which hashes the password
        $sql = "INSERT INTO
                    users(user_name, user_pass, user_email, user_date, user_level)
                VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']) . "',
                       '" . sha1($_POST['user_pass']) . "',
                       '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_email']) . "',
                       NOW(),
                       0)";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if(!$result)
        {
            //something went wrong, display the error
            echo 'Something went wrong while registering. Please try again later.';
            //echo mysql_error(); //debugging purposes, uncomment when needed
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Successfully registered. You can now <a href="signin.php">sign in</a>
                     and start posting!';
        }
    }
}
include 'footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm getting you correctly. But based on what I see, are you checking if `$_POST['user_pass']` and `$_POST['user_name']` is empty? If it is, then you are using `isset()` in completely wrong.

Comment: you can also use plain old if here like if($_POST['user_pass'))

Comment: I finally worked it out, thank you very much everyone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Null and/or empty strings are still set if the variable is declared. Try this:

`if(isset($_POST['user_pass']) && $_POST['user_pass'] != "")`

Comment: Thank you, I believe this will be the easiest way to fix my problem.

Comment: @Slerig If an answer was provided, don't forget to mark it as the answer. Cheers.

Comment: Future googlers.. the simplest way to check this is `if (!empty($var)) { ... }` You tend to learn more over the course of over 6 years and still developing. The above example will work, just more DRY with the empty method.

Answer (score 4):

isset checks that the variable is set - in this case it is set to '' (an empty string). Try using empty() as well.

Comment: This is what I thought. Thank you very much. I will try the empty() function.

Answer (score -1):

simple solution: `if(!empty($_POST['xxx']) == true)` almost equals when you use:

```
if(isset($_POST['xxx']) == true && $_POST['xxx'] != '')
```

except:
isset() regards 0(string or number) as true, while empty() regards 0 as true.

Answer (score -1):

Check this one too

```
if(isset($_POST['user_pass']) && !empty($_POST['user_pass']))
```

isset() will check that if the POST is set for 'user_pass' & !empty() will check that if the value is empty.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Answers with only code in them tend to get flagged for deletion as they are "low quality".  Please read the help section on answering questions then consider adding some commentary to your Answer.