# html form processing php script

Tags: php, javascript, html

So I have two questions. I want first to know is it possible to do things this way...
I got a html page with 2 forms which are using the same php script..

```
<?php

    if ($conn) {
        if (isset($_POST['form_student'])) {
            if ($_POST['form_student'] == 'Send') {
                if (isset($_POST['first_name']) && isset($_POST['last_name']) && isset($_POST['student_id']) && isset($_POST['gen'])) {
                    echo "<script>alert('Send information to the database.');</script>";
                } else {
                    echo "<script>alert('You didn't fill in all fields!');</script>";
                }
            }
        } 
        if (isset($_POST['form_subject'])) {
            if ($_POST['form_subject'] == 'Send') {
                if (isset($_POST['subject_id']) && isset($_POST['class_room']) && isset($_POST['day'])) {
                    echo "<script>alert('Send information to the database.');</script>";
                } else {
                    echo "<script>alert('You didn't fill in all fields!');</script>";
                }
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Alright, so first question is about, is it possible some how this way I'm doing to process that action script and show that alert box in html, without redirectiing me to script.php and than showing me the message.
Second question is, it's always echoing true even if i did not fill in all fields, instead of showing me false case.

Comment: try comparing the post value to "" for each field. isset is true if the field exists for that form http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986761/isset-function-is-returning-true-even-when-item-is-not-set-php-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in reading this tutorial:

http://jorenrapini.com/blog/javascript/the-simple-quick-and-small-jquery-html-form-validation-solution

Comment: Oh okay... I'm sorry :) You could add the script to the form page... and redirect your form information to 'self'...

Comment: Yea I was about to ask that too.. like where could I actually put that header line, and how code should look. I'm new to php so...

Comment: Just add your php into your html and `<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get" target="_blank">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>` and change your target and action to your needs

Comment: I actually don't understand what you said. Do you have a skype, so I can actually show you screenshots what I've done so far and what I want, cuz what you've just said I already did before.. but looks like you did not understand me enough..

Answer (score 0):

Familiarize yourself with AJAX, it is used to fetch info from php script without refreshing your browser.

regarding your second question, try empty() instead of isset() isset checks if the fields  are not null.

Comment: Can't use ajax..what do you think about turniing html page into php extension, and than simply without processing script.php through action, do checks before form on the same page...

Comment: Print out the values of $_POST array, the reason the if is return true must be because those fields are not empty

Answer (score 0):

Calling `isset($_POST['paramName'])` to validate something does not work. The Param will be SET, even if its `empty`. (But it's SET!) (Exception: unticked checkboxes)

Therefore, you should use `isset($_POST['paramName']) && !empty($_POST["paramName"])` instead.

To your first question: don't target `script.php`. Use the same target, containing the form, and put the logic in there (or INCLUDE script.php). Then the user will stay on the page, seeing the message or not.

Comment: Yea, looks like this worked, but now I came to idea to echo 'You didn't fill all fields!' and it prints it which seem that isset($_POST['paramName']) && !empty($_POST["paramName"]) works.. but for some reason i don't understand why doesn't want to run "<script>alert('You didn't fill all fields!');</script>";